# Android - to test in-app billing do I need to release a test application to android market?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am reading this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html and it is really confusing me :)

In one part of the tutorial, it discusses that I should make a test app and release it into google play.  And in another part of the tutorial, it discusses setting up static return values so I can mimic what google play returns to my app.

What is the right approach here if I want to test out the flow of someone buying access to a certain page?

I already have the code to buy the stuff. I just need to test that the transactions would work and the return value would be ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test with real server you need to upload your apk file as `draft version` no need to publish it.

as they says

```
 Note: Making in-app billing requests with the reserved product IDs overrides the usual
Google Play production system. When you send an in-app billing request for a reserved product
ID, the quality of service will not be comparable to the production environment.
```

so...If you want to test with your product ID you need to upload the signed version of your app on market (offcourse as draft) and also you need to pay! :)